# How to subscribe data from ZeroMQ into spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, zeromq

How can I subscribe the data in Spring which I publish with ZeroMQ in the terminal?

I'm trying to handle a get-Request, which will deliver me the Data I am receiving.

Is there like an Import? Or any annotation?

For example:

```
@Controller

public class myController {

@RequestMapping("/myGetRequest")
public String myFunction(){
     **return myDataFromZEROMQ!!??**
     }
...
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu.